# Function followed by more parameters?

Tags: node.js

How does this syntax function - `function()()`
I keep seeing functions followed by brackets with other parameters?
Any explanation or link would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed snippet showing the function you're asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're refeering to [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

The second pair of parenthesis is invoking the function immediately after it was declared.

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much I'll give this a read. First ever time asking a question the response was so fast. very much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow then. If this answer satisfies your question could you please mark it as the correct answer?